# extjs - Menu click event gets fired twice. Why?

Tags: extjs, event-handling, controller, extjs4.2

The controller that controls an event using the recommended `this.control:` construct :

```
Ext.define('Mb.controller.Sav_vpc', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function() {
        console.log('controller.init called');
        this.control({
            '#storeMenu menuitem': {
                click: this.onStoreMenuClicked
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The function `onStoreMenuClicked` gets called twice, because the `init` method of the controller gets called twice, therefore it listens twice to the event.

But when is the `controller.init()` called ? And why is it called twice ?

Here is my `application.launch` function:

```
Ext.define('Mb.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    launch: function() {
        console.log('launching app');
        var controller = Mb.app.getController('Name');
            console.log('end launching app');
    });
...
```

This will give this output in the console:

```
controller.init called
launching app
controller.init called
end launching app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `getController` inside `application.launch`, the init method of the controller gets called again, even the controller was already initialized.

I don't know if this is by design or if it is kind a bug, but I found a solution based on the [recommendations of @AlexTokarev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253885/extjs-how-correcty-call-a-controller-method-from-another-controller-or-closure/19255497#19255497) 'Inter-controller communication'.

Controller:

```
Ext.define('Mb.controller.Sav', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function(){
        this.listen({
            controller: {
                '*': {
                    savOnLaunch: this.onUserLoaded
                }
            }
        })
    },
```

Application launch:

```
Ext.define('Mb.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    launch: function() {
        this.fireEvent('savOnLaunch');
    }
```

Comment: Don't call getController() inside `application.launch`, is all. Controllers are loaded and initialized automatically by design.