# extjs - Menu definition, what is best practice following MVC principles?

Tags: extjs, menu, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I look for the best method to define the menu actions in ExtJS 4.2.

I used to define the menu action with the `handler` configuration :

```
items: [{
    text: 'About...',
    icon: Paths.img + 'information.png',
    handler: function(){MyApp.app.getController('Gui').onMenuAbout()}
},{
```

[I was adviced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255497/1951708) that this method is not good.

I now found this method : I'm using `itemId`s and the `control`-method in controllers.

My view:

```
Ext.define('Mb.view.gui.HelpMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    icon: Paths.img + 'help.png',
    menu: {
        items: [{
            text: 'About...',
            icon: Paths.img + 'information.png',
            itemId: 'menuAbout'
        },{
            ...
```

My controller:

```
Ext.define('Mb.controller.Gui', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function(){
        this.control({
            '#menuAbout': {
                click: this.onMenuAbout
            }
        })
    },
    onMenuAbout: function(){...},
    ...
```

Is this the recommended way to go or is there a better solution ?

Comment: This is a good guide to follow:  http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/guide/application_architecture

Comment: @dbrin You're right this is a good doc for MVC. But it does not talk about menus.

Comment: ExtJS deals with components. Panels, Windows, Buttons, Menus are all components and will have common standard behavior. Clearly they also have specific behaviors and events but all have common denominator.   The MVC guide lays out how to define your customized components and how to interact with them via controller. Follow it CLOSELY and you will succeed.